# getting the bottom 16 bits of a Java int as a signed 16-bit value

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, math

Hmmm. Consider this program, whose goal is to figure out the best way to get the bottom 16 bits of an integer, as a signed integer.

```
public class SignExtend16 {
    public static int get16Bits(int x)
    { 
        return (x & 0xffff) - ((x & 0x8000) << 1);
    }

    public static int get16Bits0(int x)
    { 
        return (int)(short)(x);
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (String s : args)
        {
            int x = Integer.parseInt(s);
            System.out.printf("%08x => %08x, %08x\n",
               x, get16Bits0(x), get16Bits(x));
        }
    }
}
```

I was going to use the code in get16Bits0, but I got the warning "Unnecessary cast from short to int" with Eclipse's compiler and it makes me suspicious, thinking the compiler could optimize out my "unnecessary cast". When I run it on my machine using Eclipse's compiler, I get identical results from both functions that behave the way I intended (test arguments: 1 1111 11111 33333 66666 99999 ). Does this mean I can use get16Bits0? (with suitable warnings to future code maintainers) I've always assumed that JRE and compiler behavior are both machine-independent for arithmetic, but this case is testing my faith somewhat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since numeric casts are implicit-friendly, I think the only reason you're getting the warning is that the compiler will always make the cast to int upon return, making your explicit cast redundant.

Answer (score 5):

Well, first of all the warning is correct as you can always move "up" with arithmetic conversions. Only the other way needs a cast because you might lose data (or precision for floats).

When you reduce from int to short you have to indicate that it's intentional by using a cast. But when you convert the short value back to int there's no danger and it happens automatically.

So, all you need is

```
return (short) x;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to avoid the cast, you could do it as:

```
(x << 16) >> 16
```

This technique also works with different numbers of bits. Say bottom 15:

(x << 17) >> 17

Change >> to >>> for unsigned version.

Answer (score 0):

yes, get16Bits0 should work, just add a suppressWarning metatag in front of the function.